# How to play specific Lottie animation when showing any slides in ViewPager

Tags: android-viewpager

I have an intro activity with three slides. In any of them i have one Lottie animation. I want when sliding to any of them, that animation be played.
it's my main activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_welcome">


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dots_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dots_margin_bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="ورود"
        android:fontFamily="@font/koodak"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/appBlue"
        android:alpha="0"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and any slide.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/aban"
            android:text="چت مت! چتِ راحت!"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/textView2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/koodak"
            android:text="یک پیام رسان بدون امکانات اضافه دست و پاگیر..."
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/animationView1" />

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/animationView1"
            android:layout_width="229dp"
            android:layout_height="223dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_fileName="chat.json"
            app:lottie_loop="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here my welcomeactivity.java :

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private int[] layouts;
    private PrefManager prefManager;
    LottieAnimationView xx,xx1,xx2;
//    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView2;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            launchHomeScreen();
            finish();
        }

        // Making notification bar transparent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        appCompatButtonEnter = findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        // layouts of welcome sliders
        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.activity_welcome_slide1,
                R.layout.activity_welcome_slide2,
                R.layout.activity_welcome_slide3
        };
        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(true);
        startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    //  viewpager change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(position == 0) {
                    View view = viewPager.getChildAt(0);
                    xx = view.findViewById(R.id.animationView1);
                }
                xx.playAnimation();
            }else if(position == 1){
                    View view = viewPager.getChildAt(1);
                    xx1 = view.findViewById(R.id.animationView2);
                    flag1 = true;
                xx1.playAnimation();
            }else {
                    View view = viewPager.getChildAt(2);
                    xx2 = view.findViewById(R.id.animationView3);
                    flag2 = true;
                xx2.playAnimation();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };

    private void changeStatusBarColor() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }
```

It's really a headache! when sliding I have an error and xx... cant defined...
please show me the true way

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Hope it will help you :-

```
class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(),OnPageChangeListener {

    private var myViewPagerAdapter: MyViewPagerAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var layouts: IntArray
    private lateinit var binding:ActivityWelcomeBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_welcome)
        updateViewPager()
    }

   private fun  updateViewPager(){
       layouts = intArrayOf(
         R.layout.any_slide,  R.layout.any_slide,  R.layout.any_slide
       )
       myViewPagerAdapter = MyViewPagerAdapter(layouts)
       binding.viewpager.offscreenPageLimit=2

       binding.viewpager.adapter = myViewPagerAdapter
       binding.viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(this)
       binding.viewpager.post {
           val lottie: LottieAnimationView? =  myViewPagerAdapter?.viewList?.get(0)?.findViewById(R.id.lottie)
           lottie?.playAnimation()
       }
   }

    override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        val view = myViewPagerAdapter?.viewList?.get(position)
        if(view!=null){
            val lottie: LottieAnimationView =view.findViewById(R.id.lottie)
            lottie.playAnimation()
        }
    }
    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}

}
```

**activity_welcome.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />



    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/appBlue"
        android:alpha="0"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

**View pager adapter**

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int[] layouts = null;
    public ArrayList<View> viewList= new ArrayList<>();
    public MyViewPagerAdapter(int[] layouts) {
        this.layouts=layouts;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        viewList.add(position,view);
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        viewList.remove(position);
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

**any_slide.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottie"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
        app:lottie_repeatCount="0"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/complete_guided_journey" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lottie"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```